# Reverse your code, reverse the OEIS

Tags: code-golf, sequence, source-layout

The task here is to write a program that takes an natural number, \$n\$, and produces the \$n\$th term of an OEIS sequence.  That sequence should have an identifier in the form of `A` followed by 6 digits.  Now when you take your source code and reverse the order of it's bytes to produce a new program, that program should also implement an OEIS sequence.  The new sequence should be identified by an `A` followed by the same 6 digits as last time but in reverse order (including leading zeros).

Now to keep things from being trivial neither the OEIS identifier number nor your program can be palindromes.  That is the sequences and programs should be different. You cannot choose a sequence for which it's reverse does not exist or is empty.

For each of your sequences you may choose to either use 0 or 1 indexing.  They do not have to use the same indexing. Since some OEIS sequences have a limited domain you need only output the correct numbers for the domain of the sequence.  Your required behavior is undefined outside of the domain (you can output `0`, crash, order a pizza, etc.).

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so answers will be scored in bytes with fewer bytes being better.

Comment: Do leading zeroes get included in the sequence number reversing?

Comment: @pppery They have to be, since OEIS numbers have exactly 6 digits. (it also explicitly says so in the question)

Comment: Can we take the input (index) as a string?

Answer (score 11):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>9</s> 4 bytes ([A000040](http://oeis.org/A000040) and [A040000](http://oeis.org/A040000))

```
Ø=>≠
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9o4Ob3//AMW7tHnQv@/wcA)

[!enilno ti yrT](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9o6O73/1HnAjvbwzP@/wcA)

Explanation:

```
Ø          # nth prime
 =         # output
  >≠       # ignored
```

:noitanalpxE

```
≠          # boolean negation (0 if n == 1, 1 otherwise)
 >         # increment
  =        # output
   Ø       # ignored
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 55 bytes (A055642 and A246550)

```perl6
+*.comb#}]1-_$[)4+_$^**X]_$^[)*..2,emirp-si&(perg(tros{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1uplqZgq/BfW0svOT83Sbk21lA3XiVa00Q7XiVOSysiFkhFa2rp6RnppOZmFhXoFmeqaRSkFqVrlBTlF1f/t@YqTqxUyE0sUFBL01GIMzLgsv5vBAA)

This is a anonymous Whatever lambda implementing the OEIS sequence [A055642](http://oeis.org/A055642) (length of the decimal representation of \$n\$) 0-indexed.

```perl6
{sort(grep(&is-prime,2..*)[^$_]X**^$_+4)[$_-1]}#bmoc.*+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1uplqZgq/C/uji/qEQjvSi1QEMts1i3oCgzN1XHSE9PSzM6TiU@NkJLC0hpm2hGq8TrGsbWKifl5ifraWn/t@YqTqxUyE0sUFBL01Ew1NMzMuD6bwQA)

The reverse is the sequence [A246550](http://oeis.org/A246550) (the ordered list of \$x^e\$ where \$x\$ is prime and \$e \ge 4\$) 1-indexed.

Most of this challenge was just finding a good sequence with a not too complicated reverse.

Update: Using [torcado's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188220/76162), this can be 19 bytes (A010851 and A158010)

```perl6
{256*$_**2-$_}#{21}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv9rI1ExLJV5Ly0hXJb5WudrIsPZ/cWKlQpqGkeZ/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [\/\/>](https://github.com/torcado194/worm), <s>15</s> 14 bytes ([A010851](http://oeis.org/A010851) and [A158010](http://oeis.org/A158010))

```
cn;n*-1*"Ā":j
```

effectively `cn`, output 12

```
j:"Ā"*1-*n;nc
```

effectively `j:"Ā"*1-*n`, n(256n-1)

thanks to a friend for finding incredibly simple sequences!

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 59 bytes (A030000 and A000030)

```python
f=lambda n,k=0:k if`n`in`2**k`else f(n,k+1)#]0[`n`:n adbmal
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DclBCoAgEADAryx0UetgHgVfEoEbaom6iXXp9eZcp37vdZPqPZiM5XAItCQjdYIYLNlIVgmRrM@Ph8DGzSufdrmN0wTojoK51xbphYKVhaUhnZ4pyXn/AQ)

Defines a function `f`, returning the nth term of [A030000](http://oeis.org/A030000) (smallest nonnegative number \$k\$ such that the decimal expansion of \$2^k\$ contains the string \$n\$), 0-indexed

```python
lambda n:`n`[0]#)1+k,n(f esle`k**2`ni`n`fi k:0=k,n adbmal=f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DckxDoAgDADArzRxAXVARhJeoiaUSJUAlaiLr0dvvfo@x8m6kV1axuI3BDaO3azWTk5DGlkQhDsHl/peO47/UYRklP0PcPMFs6VWr8gPFKyCxgt5D0IrKdsH)

An anonymous function returning the nth term of [A000030](http://oeis.org/A000030) (Initial digit of \$n\$), 0-indexed

---

Shorter version, which takes strings as input (for both sequences), and both still 0-indexed:

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 56 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,k=0:`k`*(n in`2**k`)or f(n,k+1)#]0[n:n adbmal
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcmxCoAgEADQXzlo8czBHIW@JAJPygrzEnPp662Wt7z81P1i01oYT0p@IWAVR21ddFIwHOyMlNHhVSCIr/oBu1lPbBlo8YnOlsvBFRJlEdTvXYsqxNsqjEbE9gI)

```python
lambda n:n[0]#)1+k,n(f ro)`k**2`ni n(*`k`:0=k,n adbmal=f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FckxDoAgDADArzRxociAjCa8RE2oUdQglSCLr0ddbrn0lP1iU70d60lxXgi450FPDXZtUCw85AtdkNI4PoCFdMH12n4FtMyRTutrygcXiJSEV793ySoTb6swGhHrCw)

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 47 bytes ([A000010](https://oeis.org/A000010) and [A010000](https://oeis.org/A010000))

Both sequences are relatively simple.

```
p n=sum[1|x<-[1..n],gcd x n<2]--2+n*n=n p;1=0 p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FctLCoAgFAXQrdxhP0WdlktoBSEhFSXl49EHHLR3ozM/m7/25ThyZpC9njjoN3Vi0FKSa9ZpRgJ1xglhaqrIErjVVoFz9IFgET33Iwo@A92Q4BL/1Uq5/AE)

`p n` = the Euler totient function of n (A000010) (1-indexed)

Reversed:

```
p 0=1;p n=n*n+2--]2<n x dcg,]n..1[-<x|1[mus=n p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpLCoAgFAXQrdxhP0WdlktoBSIhFSXl49EHGrR364zPGs5t3vecGcrqlkGWKqqNEN50hAfTuDSepNROdM@rXbpPS@CcQiRYpMD9gIKPSBckuIRTf1bK5w8)

`p n` = 1 if n = 0, otherwise n^2 + 2

It would be interesting to see an answer which doesn't use comments...